# Изменение цвета при соприкосновении

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать , чтобы во время их соприкосновения становились синими , а после обратно перекрашивались в серый.

```js
$('#button').click(function() {

  $('#id').css({
    'left': '',
    'right': '',
    'top': '',
    'bottom': ''
  });

  $('#id').animate({
    right: '8',
    bottom: '8'
  }, 3000);

  $('#id2').css({
    'left': '',
    'right': '',
    'top': '',
    'bottom': ''
  });

  $('#id2').animate({
    left: '8',
    bottom: '8'
  }, 3000);

});
```

```css
.class {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}

.class2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: gray;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id='button' name="">
<div class='class' id='id'></div>
<div class='class2' id='id2'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно каждый кадр брать от элементов `getBoundingClientRect` и их анализировать:

```js
function frame(){
  
  requestAnimationFrame(frame)

  let r1 = id.getBoundingClientRect();
  let r2 = id2.getBoundingClientRect();
  
  let notCollide = r1.x + r1.width  < r2.x || 
                   r2.x + r2.width  < r1.x || 
                   r1.y + r1.heigth < r2.y || 
                   r2.y + r2.height < r1.y;
                   
  id2.style.background = id.style.background = 
      notCollide ? 'gray' : 'blue';
}

requestAnimationFrame(frame)


$('#button').click(function() {

  $('#id').css({
    'left': '',
    'right': '',
    'top': '',
    'bottom': ''
  });

  $('#id').animate({
    right: '8',
    bottom: '8'
  }, 3000);

  $('#id2').css({
    'left': '',
    'right': '',
    'top': '',
    'bottom': ''
  });

  $('#id2').animate({
    left: '8',
    bottom: '8'
  }, 3000);
  
});
```

```css
.class {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
}

.class2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id='button' name="">
<div class='class' id='id'></div>
<div class='class2' id='id2'></div>
```